# Scale Caffe weights

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

I have trained lenet network.
When I extract weights for model I have small values like this:

```
[[ 0.06115171 -0.12328118 -0.05160818 -0.10334936 -0.01025871 -0.0503762
   -0.07576288]]
```

I need integer values for a specific application,Is there a way to train caffe with integer values or there are any scale factor due all values are near 0?.
Im looking for filters like this:

```
(1 2 1)

(0 0 0)

(-1 -2 -1)
```

Kind regards

Comment: I don't think Caffe allows integer weights, only floats.

Comment: I think that but Is there any option to scale the weights as the image i posted before?

Answer (score 1):

Although i don't use caffe it seems like your output is l2 normolized. I.e. your last layer is L2 normalization.

If you want to get integers you can apply sigmoid function to the output that currently goes into your L2 norm layer. You are still going to get float values, but they will be very close to either zero or 1. But in order for these integer values to make any sense you also need to use this output in some kind of an objective function and train with it. E.g. crossentropy with logits.

if you want to get distinct integers you can add another channel to your output with the dimension equal to the total possible unique integers you want. That way you still getting 0s and 1s but they will one-hot encode the integer values you need. Also if you going to do this you will need to apply softmax across this additional channel instead of sigmoid.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you are referring to the output of the last layer, while @user3780043 wanted to know about the internal weights of each layer.

Comment: yes @rafaspadilha is right. I need to know how can I scale values of the wights of convolutional layer , I think they are normalized but Im not sure.

Comment: it would very difficult to achieve integer weights, since the weights are the result of a continuous optimization (gradient descent), hence continuous weights